# Does Celery cache tasks? How can I reload changes in a dev environment?

Tags: python, django, docker, celery, django-celery

When using Celery, Docker, RabbitMQ and Django (with `django-celery-results` and `django-celery-beat`) I am able to load a simple task following the [tutorial](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html).

However, when I make changes to the task and reload the server (`docker-compose down`, `docker-compose up`) the changes are not reflected. Does Celery cache tasks somewhere / how to I reload them when in a dev environment? The tutorial sets `CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND = 'django-cache'` but I would assume this is destroyed by `docker-compose down`?

**For example, removing the task from both tasks.py and `CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE` in settings.py does not prevent it loading when the server is restarted.**

celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')
app = Celery('proj')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

proj/__ init __ .py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app
__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

tasks.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def hello_world():
   return print('hello world!')
```

settings.py:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'pyamqp://rabbitmq:5672'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND = 'django-cache'
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER = 'django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler'
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'hello':
        {
            'task': 'proj.tasks.hello_world',
            'schedule':
                crontab()  # execute every minute
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no autoreload function in celery ( it was removed for version 4 and it was experimental)

> The --autoreload feature has been removed.
>
> This was an experimental feature, and not covered by our deprecation
>   timeline guarantee. The flag is removed completely so the worker will
>   crash at startup when present. Luckily this flag isn’t used in
>   production systems.

You could write your own solution to watch for file changes using watchdog or something else to restart worker, or just restart container/ rerun worker

Comment: Thanks. What I don't understand is when I use `docker-compose down` this should restart the container, shouldn't it? How is it persisting?

Comment: What exactly is happening, how are you establishing that code didn't change? It would be enough to stop your containers

Comment: What operating system do you use and which docker version

Comment: Windows 10 Pro, Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b

Comment: It could be this, https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5530, bash into your container to see if file changes are there at all, also answer first question above

-> this is fixed in 2205 release 
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/#docker-desktop-community-2205

Comment: I have the same issue with it persisting...after restarting docker

Comment: You probably need to remove the docker image and then restart the container. Restarting the container alone is not enough if the application files are not being updated inside the container.